# Gradle build tool cannot find runtime.jar?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native, bintray

I am developing the react-native android app.

**My Issue:**
Today suddenly, I got an error when I tried to run my app in Android studio.

It is

```
Error:Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.jar
```

I haven't changed anything in the gradle file but it appeared suddenly. But my previous projects are working fine.

When I run the `url: https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.jar` it shows me 404 NOT FOUND.

Pleae help me with solution

Answer (score 4):

To solve the error mentioned you have to just call the maven url above jcenter() in your project gradle like below:

allprojects {

```
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/developer/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        jcenter()

    }
}
```